# How to get the attributes using PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm trying to get the attribute 'value' from the form using PhantomJS:

```
<input type="text" name="uniq_num" value="2PskzYavnHJa">
```

This is my script:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'http://example.com/';

page.open(url, function (status) {
    if (status === 'success') {
        page.injectJs('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js');
        var input = $(document).ready(function(){
        return $('input[name="uniq_num"]').attr('value');
    });

    console.log(input);
    phantom.exit();
 }
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhantomJS has a sandboxed DOM context (page context) and you can only access it through [`page.evaluate()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html):

```
page.open(url, function (status) {
    if (status === 'success') {
        page.includeJs('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js', function(){
            var input = page.evaluate(function(){
                return $('input[name="uniq_num"]').attr('value');
            });
            console.log(input);
            phantom.exit();
        });
    }
}
```

Don't confuse `page.injectJs()` with `page.includeJs()`. One of them takes a URL and a callback, because it's asynchronous, and the other one takes a local filename. Also you don't need jQuery for that:

```
page.open(url, function (status) {
    if (status === 'success') {
        var input = page.evaluate(function(){
            return document.querySelector('input[name="uniq_num"]').value;
        });
        console.log(input);
        phantom.exit();
    }
}
```

Please note:

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the `evaluate` function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
>
> **Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will *not* work!**